# Adding zero in front of small decimal places

Tags: command-line, floating-point, bc, numeric-data

so when I'm coding Im trying to have the output print out 0.12 instead of .12.
Here is my code below

```
echo -n "What is the total cost? ";
read cents
cost=$(echo "scale =2;$cost_in_cents/100" | bc);
percent=$(echo "scale =2;$percent / 100" | bc);
tip=$(echo "scale =2;$cost*$percent" | bc);
overall_cost=$(echo "scale =2;$cost+$tip" | bc);
average_cost=$(echo "scale =2;$overall_cost/${#GUESTS[@]}" | bc);
```

the output again gives me the correct output of .12 but I need a zero before the decimal place. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
value=$(printf "%3.2f\n" $(echo "scale=2; 12 / 100" | bc))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$ a=$(echo "0.1 + 0.1" | bc) && echo "$a"
.2
$ a=$(printf '0%s\n' "$a") && echo $a
0.2
```

Alternative:

```
$ echo "0.1 0.1" | awk '{printf "%.2f\n", $1 + $2}'
0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash has printf. You can do something like `printf '%.2f' $cents` to print it rounded to two decimal points. If you want to assign it to a variable, use `-v` or use the `$()` structure.